# Where can I find Google Map markers which embed location type designating icons

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I am trying to find an on-line source for the types of markers (pins) used on Google Maps, which indicate with a small icon the type of a location, such as a restaurant, school, cultural place, monument, etc.?

Also, where can markers (pins) be found which include a hollow circle near the top vs. a dot?

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Found a partial solution: placing icons only (not embedded in markers/pins) at

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/icon-complex#maps_icon_complex-javascript

Still looking for a way to easily combine small icons with markers.